# What kind of fields can be differentiated in worldbuilding?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to divide the entire concept of worldbuilding to fields? If no, why? If yes, which are the branches?

I think of fields like:

- map making
- constructed languages / language creation
- magic and/or technology building
- plot creation/lore writing

...and so on.

Comment: You forgot the most important one: sexy female-only humanoid species creation

Comment: I'm fairly certain this belongs on Meta, rather than main, as it's a question about worldbuilding itself.

Comment: What you are looking for is basically the tags. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags

Comment: @Frostfyre so do you think that question about worldbuilding itself belong to meta? I'm not sure if I agree, but I can see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Grollo no, definitely not, as they *really* vary in scope. One might be the part of another.

Comment: You should ask this question on Meta WB SE.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done but it would be interesting to try, I think you are actually more likely to end up with something like a org chart but with world building topics

Comment: @james I tried. Not exactly an org chart, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through a bunch of questions to see if I could categorize them based on your categories. It kind of worked, but I needed to tweak it a little bit for it to seem logical (to myself at least).

I ended up with the following categories. I took questions as I read them and categorized them, making each one a link in the appropriate topic.

- [Astronomical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42380/could-a-planet-be-at-the-center-of-the-universe-yet-still-have-a-sun) [Creation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42235/is-it-possible-for-one-star-to-orbit-another): [All](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42673/seasons-and-day-night-cycles-on-horseshoe-habitable-worlds) [topics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41216/starbuilding-what-is-lacking-in-the-logic-behind-cosmos-2-star-system-generatio) [relating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42426/is-a-planet-with-a-primarily-reddish-pinkish-sky-a-plausible-place-for-humans-to) [to](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42549/time-place-and-look-on-tidally-locked-planet) the features of the world or relating space that are based on physics and typically ignore any impact by the planets inhabitants.
- [Language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41547/roots-when-creating-a-language) [Development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41385/is-there-a-more-effective-way-to-build-the-vocabulary-of-a-fictional-language-th): [All](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42369/what-are-some-steps-guidelines-for-making-a-conlang) [topics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41647/how-can-i-create-a-realistic-linguistic-drift-effect) relating to the development of a language for a given world or culture.
- [Plot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/could-humans-dig-out-a-20km-tunnel-through-quartzite-by-hand) [Development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41727/how-to-defeat-the-two-party-system): [All](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42209/what-power-plant-is-the-easiest-to-reboot-and-run-by-average-joe) [topics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42244/how-could-groundhogging-work-and-what-explanation-would-require-the-least-han) [relating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42202/what-history-supports-modern-day-gladiatorial-combat) [to](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42491/what-should-humans-do-in-a-supernova) [the](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42190/what-is-the-least-impactful-thing-that-could-be-done-to-wipe-mankind-but-allow) analysis of plot events, focusing on event plausibility,their causes and effects, or how the event can be accomplished.
- [Magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41716/how-viable-are-my-glass-towers-with-arab-islamic-renaissance-technology-engine)/[Technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41869/economy-in-mirror-worlds) [Development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40948/how-would-the-lifestyle-of-people-change-if-they-learned-to-live-by-doing-photos) [and](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42282/is-an-underwater-metropolis-possible-today) [Impacts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42539/elemental-healing): [All](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/given-present-day-earth-as-we-know-it-how-could-i-fake-a-radio-transmission-as) topics relating to the design/analysis of anything non-living and the potential impacts.
- [Creature](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/what-type-of-food-might-an-organism-that-lives-its-entire-life-in-interstellar-s) [Designs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41762/could-dragons-theoretically-breathe-alcohol-based-fire): [All](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42631/why-would-an-underwater-creature-remain-lodged-to-its-prey) [topics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42617/why-would-merfolk-have-hair) [relating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42475/are-hoofed-bipeds-feasible) to the design and analysis of anything living.

Almost every topic I encountered fits fairly easily into one of these 5 topics, although some were a little tricky, either because [they](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42324/can-life-be-powered-by-thermal-conduction) [could](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42168/cheaper-faster-better-housing) [fit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42440/what-form-of-transmission-for-zombies-would-be-most-effective) [multiple](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/how-might-a-collective-such-as-the-borg-develop), or because they don't seem to fit any too [well](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42332/would-a-culture-with-magic-consider-it-magic).

Overall, it doesn't seem too difficult to divide questions into categories, but I don't know if there is a need. In most categories, you already see a lot of common tags. Although it MIGHT help to have the over-arching category that have implied sub-tags to clean things up and standardize them a bit.

Common Tags

- World Creation: planets, astronomy, stars
- Language Development: language, world-building-process
- Plot Development: (this one has a TON of different tags)
- Magic/Technology Development: alternate-history, alternate-worlds, physics
- Creature Design: Evolution, creature-design, biology

Comment: Nice Analysis, I may give it a go as well when I have time